# LocalDB does not start automatically, but start manually

Tags: sql-server, localdb

When I run my application that used LocalDB, I get the following error:

> Your SQL Server installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with (Unknown package id).

If I start manually the Local DB instance (SQLLocalDB start) it will then work! After I restart the PD, I will need to restart the LocalDB manually for my app to work.

The LocalDB version is 2014 while there is also an SQL Express 2019 installed on this machine.

Is it because there are two versions of SQL installed?

Comment: `Is it because there are to version of SQL installed?` No, I have that too and it works fine here

Comment: should be placed on Super User or DBA, but is also a self-professed dupe of [SQL Server LocalDB instance fails to start (automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011597/sql-server-localdb-instance-fails-to-start-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my query in another stack overflow:

[SQL Server LocalDB instance fails to start (automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011597/sql-server-localdb-instance-fails-to-start-automatically)

I had the link to my application in Compatibility mode for Windows 8. Just unticked that option and it worked fine.